# JavaScriptで特定の範囲の数値の配列を作りたい

Tags: javascript

Rubyでは3から6の値を持った配列を作るには以下のようにできます。

```
irb(main):001:0> [*3..6]
=> [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

これをJSで実現するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

あまり得意ではないですが、回答がないようですので回答致します。
Rubyのように連番を表現する方法はないようです。
以下で実現が可能でした。

```
start = 3
end = 6
new Array(end - start + 1).fill(null).map((_, i) => i + start)
// [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

以下が参考になりましたので記載しておきます。
https://qiita.com/Nossa/items/e420c15175d87cec079e

Answer (score 2):

ひとつの方法として、 `Array.prototype.keys` メソッドと `Array.prototype.map` メソッドを用いる方法があります。

```js
{
  const start = 3;
  const end = 6;
  [...Array(end - start + 1).keys()].map(e => e + start); //=> Array(4) [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
}
```

既に似た方法の回答がありますが、`Array.prototype.fill` メソッドと `Array.prototype.map` メソッドを用いることも出来ます。

```js
{
  const start = 3;
  const end = 6;
  Array(end - start + 1).fill(start).map((x, y) => x + y); //=> Array(4) [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
}
```

また、`Array.from` メソッドを用いることも出来ます。

```js
{
  const start = 3;
  const end = 6;
  Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start); //=> Array(4) [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
}
```

スプレッド構文とジェネレータを用いる方法もあります。

```js
{
  const start = 3;
  const end = 6;
  [...(function* (x, y) { while (x <= y) yield x++})(start, end)]; //=> Array(4) [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
}
```

Comment: 使うかどうかは別として、`((x, y) => {for(var c = [], b = x; y >= b; c.push(b++)); return c;})(start, end);` でも出来ますね。

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype` 系は既に最適化されつくしているので、別の側面から。
多くの `Array.prototype` メソッドは**値のある要素だけを処理する**ので、事前に値を代入する必要があります。

1. `Array()` で配列生成
2. SpreadElement, `Array.from()`, `Array.prototype.fill` で**値を初期化**
3. `Array.prototype.****` メソッド処理 (ループ回数 = n * 2 回)

ループ回数を `n` 回にするには、次のように書きます。

```
{
  const start = 3, end = 6;
  const result = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) result.push(i);
  console.log(result);  // [3, 4, 5, 6]
}

{
  const start = 3, end = 6;
  const result = [];
  let i = start;
  while (i <= end) result.push(i++);
  console.log(result);  // [3, 4, 5, 6]
}
```

誰もが知っている標準的な「繰り返し構文」ですが、癖のないシンプルなコードと思います。

Re: user11343782 さん